# Mongoose nested schema CastError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following data which contains a nested schema:

User Schema

```
(function userModel() {

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Entry    = require('./entry');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var usersSchema = new Schema({
    entries: [Entry]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema);

})();
```

Entry Schema

```
(function entryModel() {
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var entrySchema = new Schema({
    timeStamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    data : [Schema.Types.Mixed]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entry', entrySchema);

})();
```

I'm returning the the following error:

```
errors: 
   { entries: 
      { [CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object]" at path "entries"]`
```

As far as I can tell this is the correct way to include subdocuments. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line `module.exports = mongoose.model('Entry', entrySchema);` exports the `model` not the `schema`. You need to export `entrySchema` and use that to construct the `userSchema`

EDIT:

If you want to export both model and schema, you'd need to do something like

```
module.exports = {
  schema: entrySchema,
  model: mongoose.model('Entry', entrySchema)
}
```

In general however, you rarely ever need to export the actual model. This is because whenever you want to have access to that particular model in a different file, you would simply call `mongoose.model('Entry')` and get that model instance back. It is not necessary to call `require('.path/to/model')` just to get access to the model.

Comment: module.exports = entrySchema worked is there a way to access the schema through the previous export. Something like [Entry.Schema], is the Shema available on the export?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, I've never had to do that. I've edited my answer for an alternative however.